# IBM Message Hub - after hours of working fine it fails with SASL Handshake not supported by broker (required by mechanism PLAIN)

Tags: ibm-cloud, sasl, kafka-python, message-hub

The following application is a simple consumer which prints all messages to the console.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import confluent_kafka
consumer = confluent_kafka.Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers':   'kafka05-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093,kafka03-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093,kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093,kafka04-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093,kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093',
    'security.protocol':   'SASL_SSL',
    'sasl.mechanisms':     'PLAIN',
    'sasl.username':       'XXX',
    'sasl.password':       'XXX',
    'api.version.request':  True,
    'client.id':           'consumer01',
    'group.id':            'group01',
    })
consumer.subscribe(['logs'])
while True:
    msg = consumer.poll(1)
    if msg is not None and msg.error() is None:
        print(msg.value().decode('utf-8'))
```

In the beginning it works fine. Several hours later, I see the following error messages. Once I restart the script it works fine again.

> ^C%3|1504028772.615|FAIL|consumer01#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka08-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.]: sasl_ssl://kafka08-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093/7: Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL Handshake not supported by broker (required by mechanism PLAIN)
>   %3|1504028772.615|ERROR|consumer01#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://kafka08-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.]: sasl_ssl://kafka08-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093/7: Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL Handshake not supported by broker (required by mechanism PLAIN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a Message Hub outage at the times mentioned in your logs, so it's likely to be related to that.

Comment: Just to add to what Simon said, here is a link to the Bluemix Status Page: https://console.bluemix.net/status?tags=platform,runtimes,services,ibm:yp:us-south,ibm:yp:eu-gb,ibm:yp:eu-de,ibm:yp:au-syd,experimental_services&view=n:i